# PHP Checking ctype and strlen in single if statement

Tags: php, forms, strlen

I have a form that validates First Name, Last Name, and E-mail before processing. It seems however that something isn't working. If I enter an e-mail address and my script validates it, then the page continues regardless of the checks I have in place for First and Last Name.

HTML Form Inputs

```
First Name <input type="text" id="new_user_fn" name="new_user_fn">
Last Name <input type="text" id="new_user_ln" name="new_user_ln">
```

PHP Script

```
$ec = 0;
$fn = trim($_POST['new_user_fn']);
$ln = trim($_POST['new_user_ln']);

if(!ctype_alpha($fn) OR strlen($fn) <= 0){
    $error = "First Name cannot be blank and may only contain letters";
    $ec++;
}

if(!ctype_alpha($ln) OR strlen($ln) <= 0){
    $error = "Last Name cannot be blank and may only contain letters";
    $ec++;
}
```

Essentially this checks if the $fn is alphabetic and greater than 0 in length to ensure the user filled out the input with valid text. I go on to verify the e-mail address (this part works correctly so it has been omitted from the post) and check the value of $ec.

```
if($ec > 0){
    die($error);
}else{
    // Finish Processing
}
```

So if I leave the inputs for "fn" and "ln" blank but supply a valid e-mail address, the script still executes as if $ec = 0.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I don't see anything related to email addresses in here

Comment: That part has been proven to work so  I omitted it from the code, it happens after these checks so the script should error out regardless but does not.

Comment: If this isn't working when that does then they're probably related.

Comment: I don't see how it'd be related. If an error occurs with the first name or the last name $ec is incremented, same with the e-mail. I have proven that if you enter an invalid e-mail $ec is in fact incremented so my subsequent check of if($ec > 0) before continuing the processing stops the script but if you provide a valid e-mail $ec is never incremented even though invalid FN and LN should still trip the counter, however, they don't.

Comment: var_dump( $_POST );
echo !ctype_alpha($fn);
echo !ctype_alpha($ln);
Something is not what you think it is somewhere.  But there is nothing wrong with what you have posted there.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here. Could there be another `$ec = 0;` somewhere after this code?

Comment: array(5) { ["new_user_fn"]=> string(0) "" ["new_user_ln"]=> string(0) "" ["new_user_email"]=> string(29) "rsmith@mydomain.com" }

Comment: @Lukas - That was it. There was another $ec = 0 that I forgot to comment out. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Lukas found the issue above. Another $ec = 0 existed that was not commented out. Removing it solved the problem. Thanks all. Always nice to have an extra set of eyes sometimes. Much appreciated!